# Arduino not responding

Tags: arduino-uno, bootloader, avrdude

I have been using my arduino uno for many months and it worked very well even till today morning but an hour ago I tried to upload a sketch and arduino IDE showed my this "**avrdude: stk500_getsysc(): not in sync: resp =0x00**" , at first I thought maybe I burned my atmega32 chip but I bypassed reset and gnd with a jumper wire and opened serial monitor and my atmega32 still printing serial data,so problem must be something else,and also my led13 isn't blinking.Is it problem with bootloader?if so how can I reload bootloader in my board without using another arduino?

Answer (score 2):

I'm personally not really in to this RTFM kind of answer, but in this case it really do answer most of your questions about the bootloader part: http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/Bootloader

About the error, a quick search on SO gives you this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24240285/arduino-nano-3-avrdude-stk500-getsync-not-in-sync-resp-0x00